# Android/Libgdx How to fix this issue?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Currently iam programming on a game where you move a spaceship and try to avoid asteroids. The spaceship should move when the user touches it and so follow the finger movement of the user.
The spaceship is a sprite that moves arround with:

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {  

    x = Gdx.input.getX() - width / 2;
    y = -Gdx.input.getY() + height / 2;

}
```

The problem that i'm having right now is that the user can teleport the spaceship by touching the screen. How can i fix this? Is it possible to set a touch region?

Comment: check first when the user touches the screen, if the position that touches the screen is the spaceship..if it is then follow the movement if it's not do nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate a unit vector direction from the ship to the touch point and multiply that by a speed. You need to convert touch coordinates to world coordinates by unprojecting with the camera.

```
private static final float SHIP_MAX_SPEED = 50f; //units per second
private final Vector2 tmpVec2 = new Vector2();
private final Vector3 tmpVec3 = new Vector3();

//...

if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {  
    camera.unproject(tmpVec3.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0)); //touch point to world coordinate system.
    tmpVec2.set(tmpVec3.x, tmpVec3.y).sub(x, y); //vector from ship to touch point
    float maxDistance = SHIP_MAX_SPEED * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); //max distance ship can move this frame
    if (tmpVec2.len() <= maxDistance) {
        x = tmpVec3.x;
        y = tmpVec3.y;
    } else {
        tmpVec2.nor().scl(maxDistance); //reduce vector to max distance length
        x += tmpVec2.x;
        y += tmpVec2.y;
    }
}
```